# How do I install cyrus-sasl on 10.04 Server?

Tags: 10.04, mail-server, sasl, cyrus

[This](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/cyrus-sasl2) indicates that there is a `cyrus-sasl2` package, but it doesn't appear to be available in the repositories?

I need to install Cyrus SASL for use with postfix, not the Cyrus IMAP server.

How do I install cyrus-sasl on a 10.04 Server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's actually a list of packages. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install sasl2-bin
```